# Reduce reading documents in firebase firestore collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular6, observable

I have web app,developed using angular 6 and google-clod-firestore,which take order from customer to deliver books;Currently it have two components

1. CRM component
2. Order placing component

when customer makes call it will popup in CRM,and redirect to the order placing page.After the successful order placing it will redirect to the CRM page again.

The order placing component will show the all available books,which is coming from collection named 'books',having a size of 1000;

so each time when enters to the order placing page ,it reads 1000 document,which arises significant cost.My question is How can i reduce this reading.Is it possible to limit the read operation to once.?

currently i implemented a logic using shareReplay and singleton service,i don't know whether it is a correct implementation;

### Here is the code

```
SingeltonService.ts
 -------------------------


export class SingeltonService {
source: Observable<any>;
aa: any;
bb: any;

constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
console.log('new instance created!');
this.source = this.afs.collection('test- 
collection').valueChanges().pipe(
  tap((docs) => { console.log(`Read ${docs.length} docs`); }), 
shareReplay(1));
this.aa = this.source.subscribe()
this.bb = this.source.subscribe()

  }
}


 Order-Plcaing-component.ts
 -------------------------
export class OrderPlacingCompnent implements OnInit {

constructor(private singelton: SingeltonService){}

 ngOnInit() {}
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to generate a document that contains all the information that you want to display on that order page. Probably this would be the ID and title of each book, but likely there's much more information that you store for a book, but don't show on the order page. Since all that data in this synthesized document goes onto a single page, it should fit well within the 1MB limit on the size of a document.

This approach is quite common in NoSQL databases, where you often do additional work upon data changes, to make subsequent reads simpler/cheaper. Since reads are often much more common, this makes the reads much more scalable.

For more examples of this see the video [How to Structure Your Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haMOUb3KVSo&t=0s&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=6) in excellent [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ) sercies.